# Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: modalB is not associated to modelA

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sails.js with sequelize.js ORM. This is how I define my models to work with the associations:
https://github.com/KSDaemon/sails-hook-sequelize

model User:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    user_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    username: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING,
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
  },
  associations: function () {
    Response.hasMany(Post, { as: 'posts', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
    Response.hasMany(Response, { as: 'responses', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
  },
  defaultScope: function () {
    return {
      include: [
        { model: Post, as: 'posts' },
        { model: Response, as: 'responses' },
      ]
    };
  },
  options: {
    freezeTableName : false,
    tableName       : 'users',
    schema          : 'codigomx',
    classMethods    : {},
    instanceMethods : {},
    hooks           : {}
  }
};
```

and my model Response:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    response_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    response_content: Sequelize.TEXT,
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  associations: function () {
    Response.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', targetKey: 'user_id'});
    Response.belongsTo(Post, { foreignKey: 'post_id', targetKey: 'post_id'});
  },
  options: {
    freezeTableName : false,
    tableName       : 'responses',
    schema          : 'codigomx',
    classMethods    : {},
    instanceMethods : {},
    hooks           : {}
  }

};
```

but when I try to run this:

```
User.findOrCreate({where: {username: 'user'}, defaults: {password: 'psw'}});
```

It gives me this error: Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Response is not associated to User!

and I do have the associations correctly, can someone tell me if my associations have something wrong?

here is my repo: https://github.com/AlfredoDaAs/codigomx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a typo in the user model.

Instead of `Response.hasMany(Post, { as: 'posts', foreignKey: 'user_id' });`, it should be `User.hasMany(Post, { as: 'posts', foreignKey: 'user_id' });`