# Sequelize "include" not working white many-to-many relations

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, many-to-many, associations

I'm new to Node and Sequelize, and i'm building a basic eCommerce.
These are my **models**:

```
const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

const Sale = sequelize.define('sale', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  isDelivered: {
    type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: false,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
```

And these the **relations**:

```
Sale.belongsToMany(Product, { through: SaleItem });
Product.belongsToMany(Sale, { through: SaleItem });
```

The problem starts when I try to get the "SaleItems"

```
 SaleItem.findAll({
    include: [Product],
  })
  .then(response => {
   console.log(response);
  })
```

I get the response:

> SequelizeEagerLoadingError: product is not associated to saleItem!

It's strange, couse I'm doing the same on a one-to-many relation, and works perfectly.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I found similar question, and maybe help you. good luck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574687/unhandled-rejection-sequelizeeagerloadingerror-modalb-is-not-associated-to-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have associations between `Product` and `Sale` but not between them and `SaleItem`.

Your existing associations let you execute only queries like this:

```
Sale.findAll({
    include: [Product],
  })
  .then(response => {
   console.log(response);
  })
Product.findAll({
    include: [Sale],
  })
  .then(response => {
   console.log(response);
  })
```

You need to add associations for `SaleItem` like this:

```
SaleItem.belongsTo(Product);
SaleItem.belongsTo(Sale);
```

in order to get `SaleItem` records along with associated model instances.